# AWS Beanstalk https troubles

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

in my beanstalk app (built using laravel framework), I have the following error :
[image]

I configured the load balancer as follow :
[image]
[image]

I moved the dns servers to route 53 and created the redirection in route43.

Accessing the website through http is working correctly. Accessing it through HTTPS do not work correctly. THe first page is well called but all other calls like /image/xx.jpg or css/xx.jpg is returning a 502 Bad gateway error.

Please help me !

Answer (score 1):

found it. THe rules was not well declared in fact.

THe path pattern should be /* and not just /